# Change div when clicking on the hyperlink

Tags: html, css

I want to change the photos on the slideshow when the icon is clicked. 
            Should I use target: for this or what Html/Css element will I use?

**Here is my Html:**

```
        <!DOCTYPE.html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        </head>


        <body>
        <div id="wrapper">

        <div id="header">

        <ul>
        <li><img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/pittogrammi/142/65-32.png">Home</li>
        <li>Login</li>
        <li>Profile</li>
        <li>Service</li>
        <li>Photos</li>

        </ul>

        </div><!---------------------------header------------------->




        <!---------------slideshow--------------------->

        <ul class="slides">
            <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-1" checked />
            <li class="slide-container">
              <div class="slide">
              <img src="http://freelargephotos.com/002475_l.jpg" />
              <p class="text">/p><p class="subtext"></p>
                </div>
            <div class="nav">
              <label for="img-6" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
              <label for="img-2" class="next">&#x203a;</label>

            </div>

            </li>

            <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-2" />
            <li class="slide-container">
                <div class="slide">
                  <img src="http://freelargephotos.com/002475_l.jpg" />
                   <p class="text">Yankees Won</p><p class="subtext">The Detroit Tigers travel to the Coliseum to face the Oakland Athletics in Game 5 of the ALDS. These two teams will once again matchup to conclude the most exciting series in the 2013 postseason, thus far. Check out the live stream available online at 8 p.m. ET
        The Tigers have scored 14 runs in this series. The A's have scored 15 runs. This would explain why this series has been so tight. All games have been settled by three runs or less, two of which, were decided by one run.read more>>>>></p>
                </div>
            <div class="nav">
              <label for="img-1" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
                    <label for="img-3" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
                </div>
            </li>

            <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-3" />
            <li class="slide-container">
                <div class="slide">
                  <img src="http://freelargephotos.com/002475_l.jpg" />
                        <p class="text">Yankees Won</p><p class="subtext">The Detroit Tigers travel to the Coliseum to face the Oakland Athletics in Game 5 of the ALDS. These two teams will once again matchup to conclude the most exciting series in the 2013 postseason, thus far. Check out the live stream available online at 8 p.m. ET
        The Tigers have scored 14 runs in this series. The A's have scored 15 runs. This would explain why this series has been so tight. All games have been settled by three runs or less, two of which, were decided by one run.read more>>>>></p>
                </div>
                <div class="nav">
                    <label for="img-2" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
                    <label for="img-4" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
                </div>
            </li>

            <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-4" />
            <li class="slide-container">
                <div class="slide">
                  <img src="http://freelargephotos.com/002475_l.jpg" />
                <p class="text">Yankees Won</p><p class="subtext">The Detroit Tigers travel to the Coliseum to face the Oakland Athletics in Game 5 of the ALDS. These two teams will once again matchup to conclude the most exciting series in the 2013 postseason, thus far. Check out the live stream available online at 8 p.m. ET
        The Tigers have scored 14 runs in this series. The A's have scored 15 runs. This would explain why this series has been so tight. All games have been settled by three runs or less, two of which, were decided by one run.read more>>>>></p>
        </div>
                <div class="nav">
                    <label for="img-3" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
                    <label for="img-5" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
                </div>
            </li>

            <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-5" />
            <li class="slide-container">
                <div class="slide">
                  <img src="http://cdn3.sbnation.com/uploads/chorus_image/image/21024945/20131010_jla_sj7_324.0_standard_709.0.jpg" />
               <p class="text">Yankees Won</p><p class="subtext">The Detroit Tigers travel to the Coliseum to face the Oakland Athletics in Game 5 of the ALDS. These two teams will once again matchup to conclude the most exciting series in the 2013 postseason, thus far. Check out the live stream available online at 8 p.m. ET
        The Tigers have scored 14 runs in this series. The A's have scored 15 runs. This would explain why this series has been so tight. All games have been settled by three runs or less, two of which, were decided by one run.read more>>>>></p>
                </div>
                <div class="nav">
                    <label for="img-4" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
                    <label for="img-6" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
                </div>
            </li>

            <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-6" />
            <li class="slide-container">
                <div class="slide">
                  <img src="http://cdn3.sbnation.com/uploads/chorus_image/image/21024945/20131010_jla_sj7_324.0_standard_709.0.jpg" />
                     <p class="text">Yankees Won</p><p class="subtext">The Detroit Tigers travel to the Coliseum to face the Oakland Athletics in Game 5 of the ALDS. These two teams will once again matchup to conclude the most exciting series in the 2013 postseason, thus far. Check out the live stream available online at 8 p.m. ET
        The Tigers have scored 14 runs in this series. The A's have scored 15 runs. This would explain why this series has been so tight. All games have been settled by three runs or less, two of which, were decided by one run.read more>>>>></p>
                </div>
                <div class="nav">
                    <label for="img-5" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
                    <label for="img-1" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
                </div>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-dots">
              <label for="img-1" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-1"></label>
              <label for="img-2" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-2"></label>
              <label for="img-3" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-3"></label>
              <label for="img-4" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-4"></label>
              <label for="img-5" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-5"></label>
              <label for="img-6" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-6"></label>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <!------------------------------------>

        <div id="nav-post">

        <h1>Project</h1>

        <p>
        To my home girls here with the big butt
        Shaking it like we at a strip club
        Remember only God can judge ya
        Forget the haters cause somebody loves ya
        And everyone in line in the bathroom
        Trying to get a line in the bathroom
        We all so turned up here
        Getting turned up, yeah, yeah



        </p>
        </div>
        <hr>

        <div id="services">
        <ul>
        <li><a href=""><img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/pittogrammi/142/19-64.png"><h1>Application Integration</h1></a>
        <p>To my home girls here with the big butt
        Shaking it like we at a strip club
        Remember only God can judge ya
        Forget the haters cause somebody loves ya
        And everyone in line in the bathroom
        Trying to get a line in the bathroom
        We all so turned up here
        Getting turned up, yeah, yeah</p>
        </li> 


        <a href=""><li><img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/pittogrammi/142/21-64.png"><h1>Flexibility</h1></a>
        <p>To my home girls here with the big butt
        Shaking it like we at a strip club
        Remember only God can judge ya
        Forget the haters cause somebody loves ya
        And everyone in line in the bathroom
        Trying to get a line in the bathroom
        We all so turned up here
        Getting turned up, yeah, yeah</p>
        </li> 


        <li><img src=https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/pittogrammi/142/94-64.png><h1>Cost Savings</h1>
        <p>To my home girls here with the big butt
        Shaking it like we at a strip club
        Remember only God can judge ya
        Forget the haters cause somebody loves ya
        And everyone in line in the bathroom
        Trying to get a line in the bathroom
        We all so turned up here
        Getting turned up, yeah, yeah</p>
        </li> 



        </ul>





        </div>







        </div>



        </body>
        </html>
```

**Here is my Css:**

```
        html{
        background:background: background: #4c4c4c; /* Old browsers */
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #4c4c4c 0%, #000000 0%, #000000 0%, #595959 12%, #666666 25%, #474747 39%, #2c2c2c 50%, #111111 60%, #2b2b2b 76%, #1c1c1c 91%, #131313 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#4c4c4c), color-stop(0%,#000000), color-stop(0%,#000000), color-stop(12%,#595959), color-stop(25%,#666666), color-stop(39%,#474747), color-stop(50%,#2c2c2c), color-stop(60%,#111111), color-stop(76%,#2b2b2b), color-stop(91%,#1c1c1c), color-stop(100%,#131313)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #4c4c4c 0%,#000000 0%,#000000 0%,#595959 12%,#666666 25%,#474747 39%,#2c2c2c 50%,#111111 60%,#2b2b2b 76%,#1c1c1c 91%,#131313 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
        background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #4c4c4c 0%,#000000 0%,#000000 0%,#595959 12%,#666666 25%,#474747 39%,#2c2c2c 50%,#111111 60%,#2b2b2b 76%,#1c1c1c 91%,#131313 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
        background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #4c4c4c 0%,#000000 0%,#000000 0%,#595959 12%,#666666 25%,#474747 39%,#2c2c2c 50%,#111111 60%,#2b2b2b 76%,#1c1c1c 91%,#131313 100%); /* IE10+ */
        background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #4c4c4c 0%,#000000 0%,#000000 0%,#595959 12%,#666666 25%,#474747 39%,#2c2c2c 50%,#111111 60%,#2b2b2b 76%,#1c1c1c 91%,#131313 100%); /* W3C */
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#4c4c4c', endColorstr='#131313',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */

        font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;

        }

        #wrapper{
        width:1024px;
        margin-right:auto;
        margin-left:auto;
        min-height:1000px;
        background:#888888;
        }

        #header{
        color:#000000;
        }

        #header li{
        display:inline;
        padding:10px;
        background:#FFF;
        border-radius:12px;
        }
        /*slideshow*/
          /*slider*/
          @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Varela+Round);



          .slides {
          width:1024px;
          padding-right:65px;
          height:420px;
          display: block;
          position: relative;
          z-index:11;
          }

          .slides * {
              user-select: none;
              -ms-user-select: none;
              -moz-user-select: none;
              -khtml-user-select: none;
              -webkit-user-select: none;
              -webkit-touch-callout: none;
          }

          .slides input { display: none; }

          .slide-container { display: block; }

          .text{
           background:black;
           text-align:center;
           opacity:0.8;
           font-size:50px;
           width:30%;
           color:white;
           text-align:center;
           position:relative;
           position:absolute;
           right:100px;
           margin-top:-400px;
          }
          .subtext
          {
           color:white; 
           font-family:arial;
           font-size:15px;
           text-align:center;
           position:relative;
           position:absolute;
           right:110px;
           width:350px;
           margin-top:-260px;
          }
          .slide
          {
          top: 0;
          left:-11px;
          opacity: 0;
          margin-left:auto;
          margin-right:auto;
          width:100%;
          height:100%;
          text-align:center;
              display: block;
              position: absolute;

              transform: scale(0);
              -moz-transform: scale(0);
              -webkit-transform: scale(0);

              transition: all .7s ease-in-out;
              -moz-transition: all .7s ease-in-out;
              -webkit-transition: all .7s ease-in-out;
          }

          .slide img {
          margin-right:auto;
          width:960px;
          margin-left:-83px;
          margin-top:-10px;
          height:110%;
          text-align:center;

          }

          .nav label {
              width: 200px;
              height: 100%;
              display:none;
              position: absolute;
              margin-left:-35px;
              margin-right:110px;
              padding:auto;
              height:110%;
              opacity: 0;
              z-index: 9;
              cursor: pointer;

              transition: opacity .2s;
              -moz-transition: opacity .2s;
              -webkit-transition: opacity .2s;

              color: #FFF;
              font-size: 156pt;
              text-align: center;
              line-height: 380px;
              font-family: "Varela Round", sans-serif;
              background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .3);
              text-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgb(119, 119, 119);
          }

          .slide:hover + .nav label { opacity: 0.5; }

          .nav label:hover { opacity: 1; }

          .nav .next { right: 0; }


          input:checked + .slide-container  .slide {
              opacity: 1;

              transform: scale(1);
              -moz-transform: scale(1);
              -webkit-transform: scale(1);

              transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
              -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
              -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
          }

          input:checked + .slide-container .nav label { display: block; }

          .nav-dots {
              width: 960px;
              bottom: 0px;
            height: 1px;
            display: block;
            position: absolute;
            text-align:center;
          }

          .nav-dots .nav-dot {
            top: -5px;
            width: 11px;
            height: 11px;

            position: relative;
            border-radius: 100%;
            display: inline-block;
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
          }

          .nav-dots .nav-dot:hover {
            cursor: pointer;
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
          }

          input#img-1:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-1,
          input#img-2:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-2,
          input#img-3:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-3,
          input#img-4:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-4,
          input#img-5:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-5,
          input#img-6:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-6 {
            background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
          }
          #nav-post{
            padding-top:30px;
            color:#FFF;
              padding:20px;



            }
          #nav-post h1{
           text-align:center;


          }
          #services{
             padding-top:100px;


            }

          #services li{
          display:inline-block;
        padding:30px;





          }  
          #services img{
            background:#FFF;
            border-radius:32px;
            padding:30px;



            }
            #services p{
              width:200PX;  
        text-align:left;
              color:#FFF;



              }
```

Comment: work with javascript :)

Comment: Can you show some code snippet.

Comment: which icon do you want to click? I see the dots, the arrow, the buttons menu on top, and the content below the slideshow.

Comment: All three and each of those icons and content will show on the slider.

Comment: user e.preventDefault() in jquery to don't allow the link to go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if I get exactly what you want to do, but let me try...
You want people to get certain image on the slideshow if they click on X icon?

Well, for that you should wrap your icon with `label` element, just like your prev/next icons are doing.

```
<!DOCTYPE.html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    </head>


    <body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/pittogrammi/142/65-32.png">Home</li>
            <li>Login</li>
            <li>Profile</li>
            <li>Service</li>
            <li>Photos</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!---------------------------header------------------->
    <!---------------slideshow--------------------->
    <ul class="slides">
        <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-1" checked />
        <li class="slide-container">
            <div class="slide">
                <img src="http://freelargephotos.com/002475_l.jpg" />
                <p class="text">Application Integration</p>
                <p class="subtext">To my home girls here with the big butt Shaking it like we at a strip club Remember only God can judge ya Forget the haters cause somebody loves ya And everyone in line in the bathroom Trying to get a line in the bathroom We all so turned up here Getting turned up, yeah, yeah</p>
            </div>
            <div class="nav">
                <label for="img-6" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
                <label for="img-2" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
            </div>
        </li>
        <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-2" />
        <li class="slide-container">
            <div class="slide">
                <img src="http://freelargephotos.com/002475_l.jpg" />
                <p class="text">Flexibility</p>
                <p class="subtext">To my home girls here with the big butt Shaking it like we at a strip club Remember only God can judge ya Forget the haters cause somebody loves ya And everyone in line in the bathroom Trying to get a line in the bathroom We all so turned up here Getting turned up, yeah, yeah</p>
            </div>
            <div class="nav">
                <label for="img-1" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
                <label for="img-3" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
            </div>
        </li>
        <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-3" />
        <li class="slide-container">
            <div class="slide">
                <img src="http://freelargephotos.com/002475_l.jpg" />
                <p class="text">Cost Savings</p>
                <p class="subtext">To my home girls here with the big butt Shaking it like we at a strip club Remember only God can judge ya Forget the haters cause somebody loves ya And everyone in line in the bathroom Trying to get a line in the bathroom We all so turned up here Getting turned up, yeah, yeah</p>
            </div>
            <div class="nav">
                <label for="img-2" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
                <label for="img-4" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
            </div>
        </li>
        <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-4" />
        <li class="slide-container">
            <div class="slide">
                <img src="http://freelargephotos.com/002475_l.jpg" />
                <p class="text">Yankees Won</p>
                <p class="subtext">The Detroit Tigers travel to the Coliseum to face the Oakland Athletics in Game 5 of the ALDS. These two teams will once again matchup to conclude the most exciting series in the 2013 postseason, thus far. Check out the live stream available online at 8 p.m. ET The Tigers have scored 14 runs in this series. The A's have scored 15 runs. This would explain why this series has been so tight. All games have been settled by three runs or less, two of which, were decided by one run.read more>>>>></p>
            </div>
            <div class="nav">
                <label for="img-3" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
                <label for="img-5" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
            </div>
        </li>
        <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-5" />
        <li class="slide-container">
            <div class="slide">
                <img src="http://cdn3.sbnation.com/uploads/chorus_image/image/21024945/20131010_jla_sj7_324.0_standard_709.0.jpg" />
                <p class="text">Yankees Won</p>
                <p class="subtext">The Detroit Tigers travel to the Coliseum to face the Oakland Athletics in Game 5 of the ALDS. These two teams will once again matchup to conclude the most exciting series in the 2013 postseason, thus far. Check out the live stream available online at 8 p.m. ET The Tigers have scored 14 runs in this series. The A's have scored 15 runs. This would explain why this series has been so tight. All games have been settled by three runs or less, two of which, were decided by one run.read more>>>>></p>
            </div>
            <div class="nav">
                <label for="img-4" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
                <label for="img-6" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
            </div>
        </li>
        <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-6" />
        <li class="slide-container">
            <div class="slide">
                <img src="http://cdn3.sbnation.com/uploads/chorus_image/image/21024945/20131010_jla_sj7_324.0_standard_709.0.jpg" />
                <p class="text">Yankees Won</p>
                <p class="subtext">The Detroit Tigers travel to the Coliseum to face the Oakland Athletics in Game 5 of the ALDS. These two teams will once again matchup to conclude the most exciting series in the 2013 postseason, thus far. Check out the live stream available online at 8 p.m. ET The Tigers have scored 14 runs in this series. The A's have scored 15 runs. This would explain why this series has been so tight. All games have been settled by three runs or less, two of which, were decided by one run.read more>>>>></p>
            </div>
            <div class="nav">
                <label for="img-5" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
                <label for="img-1" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-dots">
            <label for="img-1" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-1"></label>
            <label for="img-2" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-2"></label>
            <label for="img-3" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-3"></label>
            <label for="img-4" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-4"></label>
            <label for="img-5" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-5"></label>
            <label for="img-6" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-6"></label>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <!------------------------------------>
    <div id="nav-post">
         <h1>Project</h1>

        <p>To my home girls here with the big butt Shaking it like we at a strip club Remember only God can judge ya Forget the haters cause somebody loves ya And everyone in line in the bathroom Trying to get a line in the bathroom We all so turned up here Getting turned up, yeah, yeah</p>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div id="services">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <label for="img-1" style="cursor:pointer;">
                    <img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/pittogrammi/142/19-64.png">
                     <h1>Application Integration</h1>

                    <p>To my home girls here with the big butt Shaking it like we at a strip club Remember only God can judge ya Forget the haters cause somebody loves ya And everyone in line in the bathroom Trying to get a line in the bathroom We all so turned up here Getting turned up, yeah, yeah</p>
                </label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="img-2" style="cursor:pointer;">
                    <img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/pittogrammi/142/21-64.png">
                     <h1>Flexibility</h1>

                    <p>To my home girls here with the big butt Shaking it like we at a strip club Remember only God can judge ya Forget the haters cause somebody loves ya And everyone in line in the bathroom Trying to get a line in the bathroom We all so turned up here Getting turned up, yeah, yeah</p>
                </label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="img-3" style="cursor:pointer;">
                    <img src=https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/pittogrammi/142/94-64.png>
                     <h1>Cost Savings</h1>

                    <p>To my home girls here with the big butt Shaking it like we at a strip club Remember only God can judge ya Forget the haters cause somebody loves ya And everyone in line in the bathroom Trying to get a line in the bathroom We all so turned up here Getting turned up, yeah, yeah</p>
                </label>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can also add a css class to make these elements like a "link" with `cursor:pointer;`

AND, check your HTML, take a look at your first slide `<p class="text">/p><p class="subtext"></p>` fix that `</p>` :)

Comment: Yes I would like to show each icons and the words below it to show on the slider when you click on them.

Comment: I've updated my comment with a new code, try it and tell me if this is what you want.